# Accessing a Word document from Excel VBA fails on second execution

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a simple Excel VBA routine.  It simply creates a Word object, opens a Word document, does a replace of one string in the document with another, then saves the result as a PDF, closes the original document (no-save), and the does a Quit.

The program runs fine the first time and does exactly what's intended.  However, on a subsequent run if throws an error Run-time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

I have to think that there is some clean-up that I'm not doing.  Close Excel and the next time it again works the first time, and fails thereafter.

Code is as follows:

```
private Sub btnEdit_Click()
    Dim strFN as string
    Dim wdapp as Object
    strFN = "C:\Test Document.docx"

    Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdapp.Documents.Open strFN

    wdapp.Visible = True

    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
      .Text = "<<statename>>"
      .Replacement.Text = "Colorado"
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="c:\Temp\TestDoc.pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
    ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    wdapp.Quit
    Set wdapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've searched and seen plenty of examples that essentially are the same as my code, and nobody seems to have experienced this issue. I just can't figure it why it fails after the first successful execution.

Comment: Without testing, my immediate concern is your usage of `ActiveDocument`. This is not a fully-qualified object (as in it's not a fully qualified reference to your document that you just opened). I would think that `Dim oDoc As Object`, `Set oDoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(strFN)` would qualify it appropriately, then using `with oDoc` instead of `With ActiveDocument`. Essentially, replace every instance of `ActiveDocument` with `oDoc`.

Comment: K.Davis:  Tried your suggestion.  Works every time. You rock.   Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

@K.Dᴀᴠɪs was right, and you accepted his suggestion, and everything went smoothly. What I can do is correct, guide, and clarify some of your ideas, because this is also the experience I have come through in my self-study process.

```vb
Private Sub btnEdit_Click()
    Dim strFN As String
    Dim wdapp As Object ' the Object used as representatives of the WinWord App ( the MS Word's image name is WINWORD.EXE, you can see this in your Task Manager)
    strFN = "C:\Test Document.docx"

    Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'create a instance of the WinWord app
    
    Rem already got the instance object of the WinWord, and begin use it's methoed to operate what you want to
    
    'wdapp.Documents.Open strFN 'This will be done later
    wdapp.Visible = True 'go on using it's method

    Rem Each Document has its own WinWord app, and you can open multiple instances of the WinWord app.
    Rem So you have to specify exactly which instance the document you got is in.
    'With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    Rem then use a veriable as representatives of the document you got, just like the comment guide K.'s given you
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Set oDoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(strFN) ' now you can control the document by using the variable oDoc, just like you can to the WinWord by wdapp
    Rem so use the oDoc now instead of the ActiveDocument object
    With oDoc.Range.Find
      .Text = "<<statename>>"
      .Replacement.Text = "Colorado"
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      
      'use the variable oDoc now instead of the ActiveDocument object
      .Parent.Parent.SaveAs FileNAme:="c:\Temp\TestDoc.pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
      .Parent.Parent.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
      
    End With
    
    Rem still use the oDoc now instead of the ActiveDocument object, and include them in the With ... End With block
    'ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileNAme:="c:\Temp\TestDoc.pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
    'ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
      
    Rem Close only when all the documents you want to process are finished,
        Rem otherwise you can leave it on to do the corresponding operations on other documents.
        Rem once you close the WinWord app, if you want to operate MS Word, you have to CreateObject another one to do.
    wdapp.Quit ' This is why after you run the code the first time, the next time will encounter that error because you just closed the WinWord app you created by the CreateObject method.
    Set wdapp = Nothing ' release memory occupied by the variable wdapp after quitting/closing it.
    
End Sub
```